# Google Spreadsheets: CORREL() and MMULT() with missing cases/blanks

Tags: google-sheets

So I've got the following formula to correlate two ranges:

`=ROUND(CORREL(ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT('E0:Sample'!$D$2:$AY,TRANSPOSE(SIGN(COLUMN(('E0:Sample'!$D$2:$AY)))))),FILTER(OFFSET('E0:Sample'!$D$2:$D,0,ROW()-2),NOT(ISBLANK(OFFSET('E0:Sample'!$D$2:$D,0,ROW()-2))))),3)`

The formula works fine, as long as there are no blanks in `'E0:Sample'!$D$2:$AY`. Otherwise the error message `Function MMULT parameter 1 expects number values. But '' is a empty and cannot be coerced to a number.` is thrown.

I´ve tried to filter() for empty rows, but the filter-function won't work since the ranges differ.

How do I solve this without the best way?

Thanks!

Comment: As this formula has items that do not have direct matches in Excel I have removed that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to test your complete formula, but I did a test on a mini-version of matrix multiply and it seems that you can use the N function the same way as you can in Excel. Here is my mini-test:-

=ArrayFormula(MMULT(n(B1:G1),n(A1:A6)))

where both ranges contain a mix of numbers, alphas and blanks. Non-numeric cells are treated as zeroes.

[Reference](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093357?hl=en)

I'm not totally clear about the context for this - I think you're trying to get the row sums from your large 2D array by using the mmult - if this is correct I think my answer is OK because the blanks would contribute nothing to the sums. Since CORREL ignores blanks in the second range, you don't need to filter at all?

I did eventually set up some test data for your formula, and my formula ended up like this:-

```
=ROUND(CORREL(ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(n('E0:Sample'!$D$2:$AY),TRANSPOSE(SIGN(COLUMN(('E0:Sample'!$D$2:$AY)))))),OFFSET('E0:Sample'!$D$2:$D,0,ROW()-2)),3)
```

Comment: Great! It wasn't clear to me whether there were blanks sometimes in the middle of the data or if it was only the empty rows at the end that were causing the problem. Then I started to over-think it and wonder if you should apply a correction to the row sums if there were some missing values in the data. I think the only sane way to go in this case would be to use a helper column to store the weighted sums.

Comment: Sorry, I've been busy! For some reason I'm struggling to copy your new formula from inside the comment to try and test it - I wonder if you could add it to your question because that seems to work better? Meanwhile what I think is that you should only be using N() inside the MMULT - you don't need it in the rest of the formula.